# Can I call a custom function in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have created a custom function **networkdays** in Power Query Editor.

[image: networkdays]

and I would like to call it while writing DAX code in Report Section. But I do not see the **networkdays** function available to me.

[image]

Can someone please explain the workaround?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a PQ function from DAX. They are completely separate environments. BTW, DAX already has a NETWORKDAYS() function.